# Currency Symbol for a given currency code

Tags: java, currency

I'm trying to output all currency symbol (like $ or €) in java for a given currency code. The list of currency codes can be found in http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml and the language is either "pt" or "en".

I tried already many solutions found over the internet, but some print only € other prints the currency code... but I did not found solution to print all the currency symbol in that list.

Someone can help on that?

Thanks

Comment: How are you outputting the symbol? - e.g. console/web/Android, etc., Code always helps

Comment: Note that not all currencies have single character symbols. The sign for HUF is simply the string "Ft" for example, there's no symbol.

Comment: I want to output this to a console like "USD - $" (further I will do a currency converter... but this will be later on!!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a list like this:  http://www.xe.com/symbols.php

Just read in the list and create a map of columns 1 = key, 3 = value.  Most of the currency symbols are single-character, but not all are.  That's just a fact of life.

Using the code, you can go between the symbol in this new list and the currency value in the original source you provided.

Comment: but there is no way to do this without reading an online list? like using some java method or so (like Currency.getInstance(currencyCode).getSymbol() ... )

Comment: there is no method, you must make and use your own 'lookup-table'... @http://stackoverflow.com/users/857994/w00te - nice researching!

Comment: Haha, thanks :).  amachado - you probably won't find anything like this outright for free unless maybe Google or Yahoo finance are deciding to be particularly nice.  Most financial companies like Thomson Reuters and Bloomberg make their money providing APIs that do what your asking (to much more complicated extents though).  And honestly at that, from what I've seen, the APIs usually print the ISO2 currency code and not an actual currency symbol; though I'm sure they could do either if they really had to.